# How to use the path returned by Path.iterdir() to scan the files using rglob() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I have a main directory which has many subdirectories. Each subdirectory further has various PNG files and a sub-subdirectory. My problem is summarised in the following code snippet.

```
# import
from from pathlib import Path, PurePath

# mount drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

for path in Path('/content/drive/MyDrive/Cape-Windy/Annotated-frames_COCO/').iterdir():
  print(PurePath(Path(path).rglob('*.PNG')).stem)
```

This generates

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not generator

Further experimentation:

```
for path in Path('/content/drive/MyDrive/Cape-Windy/Annotated-frames_COCO/').iterdir():
print(path)
```

generates the paths of the the sub-directories

> /content/drive/MyDrive/Cape-Windy/Annotated-frames_COCO/Cape_Windy-546053-processing_1-2020-10-25-19-29-44-759-coco-1.0.zip
> ...
> and

```
for path in Path('/content/drive/MyDrive/Cape-Windy/Annotated-frames_COCO/').iterdir():
print(Path(path).rglob('*.PNG'))
```

gives

> <generator object Path.rglob at 0x7f1c9b7d2f20>
> ...

Based on the documentation, I suspect that what's being returned by Path.iterdir() may be a PosixPath instance. Though I'm not sure what type is needed to make my code work. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Code is written in Python 3 in google colab, and all data is in the google drive.

Comment: `.rglob` returns a generator object, i.e. an iterator. This is reasonable, because a glob can match many paths. So you have to iterate over that.

Comment: However, there is no need to use iterdir, you can use a glob pattern that will search the directory tree directly

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Clarification: What I am trying to achieve in my work requires iterating over the main directory in the first step, and then scanning the subdirectories for files. In my question, I have reworded the actual problem to obscure unnecessary details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is because the Path.rglob method returns a generator object, which is not a string, bytes or os.PathLike object. To get the base name of each PNG file without the extension, you'll need to loop through the generator and extract the stem of each file. Here you go this should solve the issue.

```
from pathlib import Path, PurePath

# mount the drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

base_dir = Path('/content/drive/MyDrive/Cape-Windy/Annotated-frames_COCO/')

# loop through each subdirectory
for subdir in base_dir.iterdir():
    # loop through all PNG files in the subdirectory and its subdirectories
    for png_file in subdir.rglob('*.PNG'):
        # print the stem of each PNG file
        print(PurePath(png_file).stem)
```

This code loops through each subdirectory, then for each subdirectory it loops through all PNG files (including those in sub-subdirectories) and prints the stem of each file, which is the base name without the extension. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old Topic, but I think that you can write the loop shorter and start straight from the base path, since `Path.rglob()` will iterate recursively for you:

> (method) def rglob(pattern: str) -> Generator[Path, None, None]
>
> Recursively yield all existing files (of any kind, including
> directories) matching the given relative pattern, anywhere in this
> subtree.

So you could rewrite the code in a single line loop without `Path.iterdir()`:

```
from pathlib import Path

# mount the drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

base_dir = Path('/content/drive/MyDrive')

# loop through each subdirectory and print the stem of each PNG file
for p in base_dir.rglob('*.PNG'):
    print (p.stem)
```